# How to change your Volume with your Hp 2007 Keyboard on Mac

Tags: macos, macos-ventura

I use an Hp 2007 Keyboard on a Mac. My problem is I don't have fn keys nor do I have command keys. As they've been replaced with the window logo. I can not change my volume nor do I know what the window logo keys do. Please help.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Isn't that just what I said? :-D That's what it does having one's studio packed up  for over half a year...

Comment: @Tetsujin - LOL yeah I did, hence deletion the incorrect advice :-D I've used for a few years with my MacBook an external Win kbd (didn't find an ergonomic one for Mac), but as it's been packed for months I forgot... and I'm a touch typist anyhoo so don't usually look at it very often :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need an Apple keyboard for the F-Keys to be recognised as 'special feature' keys.
With an Apple keyboard you can toggle whether the F-keys works as regular F-keys or special feature [volume, brightness etc]…

[image]

If you connect a Windows keyboard, this section, marked in red, is missing.

Your only option would be to add a volume slider to the menu bar…

[image]

You can then adjust it with the mouse.

On a standard Windows keyboard, the modifiers to the left;  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  remains Ctrl,  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  is Option, & <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> acts as Command.
To the right,  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  acts as though you pressed Ctrl & Opt together, Alt & Ctrl should remain as on the left [if they exist]. The Menu key has no purpose on Mac.
On a wired keyboard, these should work right from the boot chimes, if you need to enter Recovery etc. Wireless keyboards sometimes will not respond until further into the boot process, preventing you from getting into Recovery or changing startup volume. If that ever happens, you may need an Apple wired keyboard temporarily. [I have to do this for my Logitech Wireless 'PC' keyboard to get to Recovery.]

Comment: To complete - @PIRATE, [here's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/keyboard-mappings-using-a-pc-keyboard-on-a-macintosh-d4fd87ca-8762-30ee-fcde-08ffe95faea3) Microsoft KB article on Win keyboard mapping on a Mac, and [here's](https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/17/how-to-remap-windows-keyboard-buttons-match-mac-layout/) 9to5mac's article on how to remap the Win keyboard for Mac.